# Почему редакторы векторной графики всё портят и как от этого избавиться?

Tags: svg, inkscape, illustrator

По факту вопрос один, как правильно сохранить SVG, чтобы в последствии его можно было редактировать без проблем?

Если коротко, то столкнулся с проблемой  при экспорте в SVG из векторных редакторов Illustrator или Inkscape. Возникает проблема при последующем открытии, - что-то, куда-то, улетает или пропадает.

Например при экспорте из Illustrator и последующем открытии в нем пропадает (т.е. исчезают из структуры документа) часть текстовок. Так же может выпасть из документа часть элементов, если была применена `clip mask`.

Еще одна проблема в нем же, если ты сделал элемент без заполнения у него `fill` аттрибут, то будет отсутствовать в DOM, а если ты отрисовал с заполнением а потом удалил заполнение? получишь атрибут `fill="none"` в DOM.

Inkscape тоже доставляет проблемы,- нельзя просто так открыть SVG с `presentation attributes` и сохранить его потому, что он сохранит оформление в стилях. Так же экспорт в SVG в `inkscape`  приводит к его не читабельности в том же Illustrator. А так же его большая медлительность с этими файлами и часть элементов может, также улетать, причем обычно это другая часть, но это происходит реже чем в Illustrator.

На удивление браузеры SVG отрисовывают так, как она выглядела на момент сохранения в редакторе.

Данные проблемы возникают на тяжелых файлах со сложной структурой (под сложной структурой имеется в виду большое количество не примитивов, а группировок, `clip` и `mask`) и размером от 3мб до 7мб

Comment: А зачем редактировать экспортированный svg? У вас должен быть родной ai. Никто не обещал, что результат экспорта можно нормально импортировать обратно.

Comment: я редактирую svg в ide

Comment: @ StrangerintheQ читал в твоих комментариях, что и  оптимизатором от Peter Collingridge тоже пользуешься

Comment: @AlexeyTen с удовольствием буду работать только с ai если подскажкте как пакетно в нескольких десятках документов поменять плейсхолдеры на данные из стороннего источника, а потом экспортировать в растр...

Answer (score 2):

> На удивление браузеры svg отрисовывают так как она выглядела на момент
>   сохранения в редакторе...

Если конкретно речь идёт о редакторе `Inkscape` то, как мне кажется вся проблема в том, что он бесплатный. И разработчики добавляют служебную информацию в файл, чтобы при открытии файла был трафик на их сайт. Надо же как-то отбивать бесплатность редактора.
Но это сугубо моё мнение :-)

Для примера вот так выглядит код окружности, нарисованной в `Inkscape`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="40"
   height="40"
   viewBox="0 0 40 40"
   id="svg2"
   sodipodi:docname="Shape-circle.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata8">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs6" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1400"
     inkscape:window-height="987"
     id="namedview4"
     showgrid="true"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
     inkscape:zoom="11.8"
     inkscape:cx="17.033898"
     inkscape:cy="20"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid815" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="40,5"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide817"
       inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="0,5"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide819"
       inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="20,12.881356"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide821"
       inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="35,0"
       orientation="0,1"
       id="guide823"
       inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="31.864407,20"
       orientation="0,1"
       id="guide825"
       inkscape:locked="false" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="32.372881,40"
       orientation="0,1"
       id="guide827"
       inkscape:locked="false" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <circle
     style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#00e700;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="path829"
     cx="20"
     cy="20"
     r="18.135593" />
</svg>
```

**Как убрать всю эту служебную информацию?**

Для оптимизации кода есть оптимизатор - [SVG-EDITOR](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) от **Peter Collingridge**

Интерфейс редактора прост и интуитивно понятен.

- На первой вкладке **"Input"** копируем в окно содержание svg файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- На второй вкладке - **"Optimise"** набор чекбоксов, выбирая которые
  можно гибко настроить режим оптимизации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В группе радиокнопок -`Optimisation` - три набора режимов оптимизации.

- Допустим выбираем самый жёсткий режим - `Extreme (may alter image
  quality)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Необходимо отключить следующие чекбоксы:

`Remove whitespace` - иначе код будет идти сплошной строкой
`Combine paths where possible` - иначе все формулы патчей будут соединены вместе

- Далее в `Decimal places` выбираем или оставляем как есть (1)
  количество знаков после запятой.     При этом смотрим на изображение в окне, если происходят изменения в сторону ухудшения изображения, то количество знаков нужно увеличить.

В реальном режиме времени при изменениях настроек оптимизации будет показываться размер оптимизированного файла, который уменьшается по сравнению с не оптимизированным файлом в несколько раз.

Вот код после оптимизации с помощью **SVG-EDITOR**

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="18.1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#00e700"/>
</svg>
```

*Сравните насколько стал короче код после оптимизации `svg-editor`*

**Update**

Обратите внимание на это объявление `Namespace`, которое появляется после обработки svg-editor.

```
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Оно не совсем корректно, поэтому его необходимо вручную заменить на:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

Если не заменить `Namespace` на правильную запись, то не будут работать команды использующие ссылки по `id`

Comment: Мне ещё этот оптимизатор нравится https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ Пока не подводил.