# Как нарисовать букву Z для иконки?

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Мне нужно нарисовать букву `Z` на SVG для иконки.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
       <path d="M2 0h28a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v28a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 
       0 1 2-2z" fill="#e35604"></path>
       <path d="БУКВА Z"></path>
    </svg>
```

Чтобы получить такую иконку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ответ @Air правильный, красивый и будет полезен в любом случае.

Но, так как символ `Z` нарисован двойным контуром, будет невозможно сделать анимацию рисования буквы по всей ширине строки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стрелками показаны узловые точки.

Чтобы нарисовать **одиночный контур** нужно выбирать в векторном редакторе инструмент - `Рисовать кривые Безье и прямые линии` - <kbd>Shift+F6</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы убрать из файла SVG лишнюю информацию, которую сохраняет векторный редактор необходимо оптимизировать файл с помощью любого оптимизатора, например - [SVG EDITOR](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)

Как пользоваться оптимизатором - [подробно, на примерах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978862/28748)

[Другие оптимизаторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784173/28748)

На выходе получаем код:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" >
  <!-- Прямоугольник с закругленными углами -->
  <path d="M2 0h28a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v28a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 
       0 1 2-2z" fill="#D94937"></path>
 <!-- Символ Z -->
 <path  d="M6.5 4.3H25.9v2.3l-18 19.1 0 2.2 19.4 0" style="fill:none;stroke-width:4;stroke:white"/>
  </path> 
</svg>
```

Чтобы сделать SVG адаптивным ширину и высоту холста SVG нужно указывать в процентах

`width="15%" height="15%"`

### Анимация контура `"Z"`

Полная длина контура буквы равна `70px`

Анимация рисования линии достигается изменением `stroke-dashoffset` от максимума до нуля `values="70;0"`

```html
<svg xxmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" style="fill:">
  <!-- Прямоугольник с закругленными углами -->
  <path d="M2 0h28a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v28a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 
       0 1 2-2z" fill="#D94937"></path>
 <!-- Символ Z -->
 <path stroke-dasharray="70" stroke-dashoffset="70" d="M6.5 4.3H25.9v2.3l-18 19.1 0 2.2 19.4 0" style="fill:none;stroke-width:4;stroke:white"> 
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  values="70;0;0"
  dur="2s"
  fill="freeze"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path> 
</svg>
```

*Вариант рисования - туда-обратно*

```html
<svg xxmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" style="fill:">
  <!-- Прямоугольник с закругленными углами -->
  <path d="M2 0h28a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v28a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 
       0 1 2-2z" fill="#D94937"></path>
 <!-- Символ Z -->
 <path stroke-dasharray="70" stroke-dashoffset="70" d="M6.5 4.3H25.9v2.3l-18 19.1 0 2.2 19.4 0" style="fill:none;stroke-width:4;stroke:white"> 
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  values="70;0;0;70;70"
  dur="5s"
  fill="freeze"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @webphp специально написал подробно, потому что вы сказали, что совсем не знаете SVG. Задавайте ещё вопросы, - я или другие ребята всегда с удовольствием ответят.

Comment: 1. Не пойму, как у тебя вертикальные срезы получились. 2. А что в коде делает дуга?

Comment: @Qwertiy а вот за счёт этих дуг и получил вертикальные срезы. Обрати внимание, что узловых точек не 4, а 6

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а можешь подробнее? Кстати, width и height я вообще предпочитаю удалять.

Comment: @Qwertiy посмотри дополнительный ответ, сделал отдельным ответом, чтобы не запутать людей

Comment: @Qwertiy Разобрался? Ответ устроил?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ага, какая-то хитрая прямая дуга.

Comment: @Qwertiy просто очень маленький радиус `a2`

Answer (score 7):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
       <path  fill="#e35604"  d="M385,400H15c-8.3,0-15-6.7-15-15V15C0,6.7,6.7,0,15,0h370c8.3,0,15,6.7,15,15v370
   C400,393.3,393.3,400,385,400z"/>
       
      <path fill="white" d="M50,50 350,50 350,100 150,300 350,300 350,350 50,350 50,300 250,100 50,100z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

Такое элементарно строится "by hand" - по точкам:

`d="M-12,-12 h23 L-12,12 h23"`

```css
path {
  animation: 2s fill;
}

@keyframes fill{
  from {stroke-dasharray: 0 100}
  to {stroke-dasharray: 100 100}
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-20,-20,40,40 height=100px width=100px>
  <rect x=-17 y=-17 width=34 height=34 rx=5 fill=orange></rect>
  <path d="M-12,-12 h23 L-12,12 h23" stroke=white fill=none 
        stroke-miterlimit=2 stroke-width=5></path>
</svg>

<svg viewbox=-20,-20,40,40 height=100px width=100px>
  <rect x=-17 y=-17 width=34 height=34 rx=5 fill=orange></rect>
  <path d="M-12,-12 h23 L-12,12 h23" stroke=white fill=none 
        stroke-linejoin=round stroke-linecap=round 
        stroke-width=5></path>
</svg>

<svg viewbox=-20,-20,40,40 height=100px width=100px>
  <defs><mask id=mask>
    <rect x=-12 y=-15 width=24 height=30 fill=white></rect>
  </mask></defs>
  <rect x=-17 y=-17 width=34 height=34 rx=5 fill=orange></rect>
  <path d="M-12,-12 h23 L-12,12 h23" stroke=white fill=none 
        stroke-width=5 mask=url(#mask)></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: (+1) [посмотри дополнительный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1033194/28748) в случае 4-х точек края невозможно вертикально обрезать  и `stroke-linecap=round` и другие атрибуты не помогут

Comment: @Alexandr_TT пока ты писал коммент я добавил это =)

Comment: а что добавил то, вроде всё равно вертикальную обрезку не вижу в твоем ответе

Comment: @Alexandr_TT https://i.imgur.com/diGS0kS.png

Comment: ух ты .. маски режут Просто интересно, а как будет выглядеть анимация рисования линий. Добавишь?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT 2 мин

Comment: Здорово. Зачёт!

Answer (score 6):

Так ?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="10" fill="#d94937" />
<text x="25" y="75" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:900;font-size:100px;fill:#fff;"> z </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне нужно с помощью полосы нарисовать Z, т.е. чтобы в одном <path d="БУКВА Z"></path> было

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

Дополнительные пояснения по комментариям

Хватило бы 4 узловых точек для начертания `"Z"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в этом случае  невозможно сделать вертикальную обрезку, как в образце автора вопроса

Поэтому я добавил две дополнительные точки, сменил их тип на - `сделать выделенные узлы автоматически сглаженные`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И перемещая рычаги управления этих узловых точек добился вертикального среза

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]